# Should I cite the interviewer or the interviewee when citing a news article?

Tags: citations

I was wondering what would be the appropriate technique to cite an interviewee from a news article. I would imagine this is fairly common in some texts, but I could neither find any mention of it in my school's guidelines nor in stackexchange or google.

So for example, if I was to quote Edward Snowden from an article written by someone else, would I reference (Snowden, 2015) or (Palmer, 2015) or something else?

I'm currently using APA style it must be noted.

Palmer, D. (2015, June 2). Snowden slams UK governments attempts to secretly pass legislation allowing GCHQ to ‘hack anybody’s computer’. Computing.co.uk. Retrieved from http://www.computing.co.uk/ctg/news/2411261/snowden-slams-uk-government-attempts-to-secretly-pass-legislation-allowing-gchq-to-hack-anybodys-computer on 13th November, 2015.

Comment: "According to (Palmer, 2015), Edward Snowdon said '...'.

Comment: @user3697176 Better, "According to Palmer (2015), Snowden said ...", but the "According to" bit is really redundant if you cite a source.

Answer (score 8):

A standard MLA method for citing a published interview is described [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/09/):

> [Interviewer]. Interview with [Interviewee]. [venue] (year): [pages]. [medium].

e.g.,

> Lois Lane.  Interview with Superman. Daily Planet (1963): 12-13. Print.

As noted in the comments, you would then refer to it in text using per the style with whatever prose is most clear and lucid, e.g., "In an interview with Lois Lane (Lane, 1963), Superman claimed that his only weakness was kryptonite."

Citing in the [APA style appears to be similar](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/quick-guide-on-references.aspx), and all other styles should have an equivalent as well.